# Function starts before click event

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

My question is why even `closeButton()` has a `click` event inside it, this `click` event happens when the first anonymous function is called on click.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior? My goal here is that the `click` event on the second function just happens after the second click, if I click the `searchToggler` it calls the function and when I click anywhere it calls the second `click` function.

```js
const searchToggler = document.querySelector(".search-toggler");
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-wrapper");
const searchImage = document.querySelector(".search-icon");


searchToggler.addEventListener("click", function () {
    searchWrapper.classList.toggle("search-wrapper-active");
    searchImage.classList.toggle("search-active");

    closeButton();

    function closeButton() {
        $(document).click(function (e) {
            console.log(e.target);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I think function `closeButton()` should be outside the event listener

Comment: but closeButton() must start just if the first function is activated

Answer (score 0):

Place the `closeClick()` function on the outside, as it only needs to be created once. Then add/remove event listeners when you need to:

```js
searchToggler.addEventListener("click", function () {
    searchWrapper.classList.toggle("search-wrapper-active");
    searchImage.classList.toggle("search-active");
    
    // Add to window instead with an event listener after a timeout, to prevent click from firing immediately
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.addEventListener('click', closeClick);
    }, 100);
}

function closeClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target);

    // Remove it again if needed
    window.removeEventListener('click', closeClick);
}
```

Comment: But even here the console.log happens when I click the first function trigger

Comment: Might be because the mouse-up is triggering the click. Ive adjusted the answer to have a timeout around the addEventListener, check if that helps